# Joining a query across servers using Zend_Db and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework

In SQL Server there is a syntax for joining a query across two servers where you use the following:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(StatsTotal) AS ChannelTotal 
FROM [SERVER\DB4_1].DBNAME.dbo.Stats AS Stats
```

This means that I can connect to one server and then ask the query to execute on another server using a feature of SQL Server called 'linked servers'. My problem is that in `Zend_Db` there is no way to use this feature that I can see with `Zend_Db_Select`.

Currently I'm trying to use the following code:

```
$select = $this->db->select();
$select->from(array('Stats' => '[SERVER\DB4_1].DBNAME.dbo.Stats'), array('ChannelTotal' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(StatsTotal)')));
echo $select->assemble();
```

Which gives me the following SQL in response:

```
SELECT SUM(StatsTotal) AS "ChannelTotal" FROM "[SERVER\DB4_1]"."DBNAME" AS "Stats"
```

Obviously this will not work, so is there an alternative way to do this without having to hand-write these queries?

Comment: Have you tried using `'Stats' => new Zend_Db_Expr('[SERVER\DB4_1].DBNAME.dbo.Stats')`?

Comment: ARGH! Amazing, can you put that as a question so I can award some points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `'Stats' => new Zend_Db_Expr('[SERVER\DB4_1].DBNAME.dbo.Stats')` should work.